# Substring, Replace, finding the next word etc in C#

Tags: .net, string, replace, substring

This is seems to be tricky and I stumble on the last hurdle. I tried different logics, but din quite work. So I dont provide my code. But I'll post what output I need. It's a matter of logic I guess though i'm sure i do need to certainly know methods more than `.Substring()` and `.Replace()`.

Input is a string. and the output is an altered form of the input string. Here's what i want.

input: "happy"
output: "happy"

input: "he is a cheat"
output: "he is a cheat"

input: "he c h e a t e d me"
output: "he c h e a...t e d me"

input: "this is my p a r r o t"
output: "this is my p a...r r o t"

That's at times few particular words in the string in my program can be separated by a space(parrot, cheated in the above examples). What I want to happen is

```
      .Replace("a ", "a...");
```

Whenever there is "a" in the words split with space(p a r r o t, c h e a t e d), I want three dots to follow "a". I can do that. What compounds my problem is "a" is also a common word in english use to denote "one" (a mango, an apple etc). I dont want the program to add three dots after such "a's". An example below.

input: "m a n g o is a fruit"
output: "m a...n g o is a fruit"

How can this be done? Any logic would do if it gives the output as I desire. I hope I could make my requirement clear. If I miss anything please ask.
Thanks

Comment: I would read up on parsers if I were you. You've left the realm of simple text manipulation if you've got rules like that. You need to turn each component into a token, and logically determine what combination of tokens produce what output.

Comment: I dont know what's parses and whats token. All i know is .Substring and .Replace methods in C#. Can you provide the code?

Comment: I'm curious to know *why* you want to do this? It's hard for me to imagine a scenario where this makes any kind of sense?

Comment: @Mark, lol.. Yes this is a curious case indeed. I'm using the espeak text to speech engine in my program and what i do is run the command line from background as a separate process. So in a spelling tool i want the application to dictate the spellings one by one - alphabet by alphabet. So if i type "y e l l o w" it reads each letter y,e,l,l,o and w. But strangely if there's letter "a" like as in "c h e a t e r", the letter "a" is read so fast that it ain't clear at all. So I wanted to give a delay after reading "a". "a..." does the trick. Hope that answers :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in the cases you mentioned...

```
string input = "once a c h e a t e r always a cheater";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\b\w )a (?=\w\b)", "a...");
Console.WriteLine(output); // once a c h e a...t e r always a cheater
```

It checks that the surrounding "words" are a single letter.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I guessed it that i can do this easily by going for regular expressions. which im not an expert of. Thanks. I used this:

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: @Mark, this method doesnt insert "..." if the word is starting with "a". suppose the input is "thin a i r", the output is the same. not "thin a...i r" .. what can be done?

Comment: @nawful: Yes. Just change the regex to `@"a (?=\w\b)"`. You haven't clearly defined when and where you want the ...s to appear, so it's hard to give you a definitive answer. For example, "a c h e a t e r". Is the first 'a' apart of 'acheater' or is it its own word?

Comment: @Mark: In "a c h e a t e r" I want the out out to be "a c h e a...t e r". But I know this is difficult considering the logic you have used. But doesnt matter. I prefer getting the output "a...c h e a...t e r" than getting "a c h e a...t e r" (considering i have many words starting with "a") with your present logic. Though your new code doesnt do exactly what i wanted, this does the job better than the previous. So let me edit it. A big thankssss.. :)

Comment: You're welcome. You'll have to use a dictionary if you want much better results than that, otherwise there's just no way to know where to split it.

Comment: @Mark, I feel regex is such a big tool in C# that one shouldn't leave it without learning. I want to master it. You are an incredible programmer too ;)

Comment: @nawful: Haha, thank you :) Such high praise. Yes, regex is a big tool any language... any time you have to do string processing, it comes in handy. Definitely worth the time to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try,
find substring 'a',fetch next string and if after occurance of a thr is a string which is like character space character space then replace that a with a...

Comment: Yes i do know that. But my problem is it does the same even for the normal "a" we use in english. that shouldnt happen. i mentioned that part towards the ending of my post. please read. can u post the code itself if u have idea?

Comment: but in a normal occurance of a ,after a there will be a word and you can check for word such as a space someother character space someother character space then replace that a.for that you need to create an array ,make a at oth position ,space 1st position ,charcter 2nd position ,space 3rd posion and character 4th position and stop searching ahead and check if this pattern follows replace the a with a...

Comment: thats the core logic, you are right. thats what i tried. but i stumble at the last hurdle. i will appreciate if you can provide the code snippet itself.